# One-to-one mapping of 'between' values?

Tags: r, loops, boolean

I am trying to map with a one-to-one relation of values that returns a dataframe when the values are between two values. For example on this dataset:

```
                       Coastal_Cities Summer_2009 Summer_2010 Summer_2011 Summer_2012 Summer_2013 Summer_2014 Summer_2015 Summer_2016 Summer_2017 Summer_2018 Summer_2019
1                        Aberdeen City         497         434         437         310         541         556         556         492         474         616         526
2                    Barrow-in-Furness         552         555         637         445         671         726         616         514         547         773         627
3                            Blackpool         551         550         623         433         664         700         585         493         535         738         611
```

Try to map with a one-to-one relation each value in the row, relative to the values between the upper and lower confidence, if not then set to 0.

```
   lower_confidence upper_confidence
1          479.8784         509.0307
2          588.6927         622.7619
3          573.3041         605.4232
```

So row 1 should map to row 1, row 2 should map to row 2 etc ...

For example, given a set of values:

```
structure(list(Coastal_Cities = c("Aberdeen City", "Barrow-in-Furness", 
"Blackpool", "Bournemouth, Christchurch and Poole", "Caerdydd - Cardiff"
), Summer_2009 = c(497, 552, 551, 654, 529), Summer_2010 = c(434, 
555, 550, 642, 598), Summer_2011 = c(437, 637, 623, 567, 549), 
    Summer_2012 = c(310, 445, 433, 481, 433), Summer_2013 = c(541, 
    671, 664, 776, 733), Summer_2014 = c(556, 726, 700, 799, 
    741), Summer_2015 = c(556, 616, 585, 619, 621), Summer_2016 = c(492, 
    514, 493, 598, 524), Summer_2017 = c(474, 547, 535, 659, 
    569), Summer_2018 = c(616, 773, 738, 806, 730), Summer_2019 = c(526, 
    627, 611, 688, 561)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

#Get its 95% confidence interval by rows
ci <- function(x){
z= rowMeans(x[,-1])-1.96*(apply(x[, -1], 1, sd)/length(x[,-1])); 
v =rowMeans(x[,-1])+1.96*(apply(x[, -1], 1, sd)/length(x[,-1])) ;
y=data.frame(lower_confidence = z, upper_confidence = v);
return(y)}
```

Now I am trying to produce a function that stores those values in each row that are between the upper and lower interval:

```
diff_ci <- function(x, y) { 
  
  for(i in nrow(x)) {
    for(j in length(x[, -1])){
  t = x[j] > ci(y)[1][[1]][i] 
  p = x[j] < ci(y)[2][[1]][i]
  
    } 
    
  }
  e = data.frame(t, p)
  return(e)
}
```

However, when I call the function I get an output that I cannot seem to interpret what exactly is it representing by the :

```
diff_ci(weather[, -1], weather)

 Summer_2018 Summer_2018.1
1        FALSE          TRUE
2         TRUE         FALSE
3         TRUE         FALSE
4         TRUE         FALSE
5         TRUE         FALSE
```

It is not clear to me that it has done anything that I had in mind for.

As when I run this into a lapply function:

```
> lapply(weather[, -1], diff_ci, y=weather)
```

I get the error:

> Error in data.frame(t, p) : object 'p' not found

I am guessing I messed up with the allocation of arguments within the for-loop?

My expected output (for first 2 rows):

```
                       Coastal_Cities Summer_2009 Summer_2010 Summer_2011 Summer_2012 Summer_2013 Summer_2014 Summer_2015 Summer_2016 Summer_2017 Summer_2018 Summer_2019
1                   Barrow-in-Furness         497         0         0         0         0         0         0         492         0         0         0
2                           Blackpool         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
```

I am also expecting a cleaner version from the interpretation of my code with an explanation as to how I went wrong?

EDIT:
I have also tried this which fixes some of the `i` /`j` uses, however it just prints the entire output ...:

```
diff_ci <- function(x, y) { 
  
  for(i in nrow(x)) {
    for(j in length(x[, -1])){
  if(x[[j]][i] > ci(y)[1][[1]][i] | x[[j]][i] < ci(y)[2][[1]][i]){
    print(x)
  }
  
    } 
    
  }

}
diff_ci(ten_year.average[, -1], ten_year.average)
```

Comment: Your `611` in summer-2019 is in the third row, not second ... am I missing something that it should be moved?

Comment: @r2evans Good eye ... I must have printed and copied the wrong length of the output hence the first table of the code is missing the first row. I hadn't noticed this ... Although, I think it still paints the picture. However, I am happy to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your question it seems to me that what you need is fairly straight forward. If a value falls within the rowwise confidence interval  provide that value. If a value is outside the confidence interval return 0. I named the data you supplied `reprex`.

I'm not sure what your use case is, so I didn't really fiddle with your ci calculation except to pull it out of a function so you can step through building the dataframe.

```
min <- 
  sapply(seq_along(reprex$Coastal_Cities), 
         function(x) {
           rowMeans(reprex[x,-1])-1.96*(apply(reprex[x, -1], 1, sd)/length(reprex[x,-1]))
           }
         )

max <- 
  sapply(seq_along(reprex$Coastal_Cities), 
         function(x) {
           rowMeans(reprex[x,-1])+1.96*(apply(reprex[x, -1], 1, sd)/length(reprex[x,-1]))
           }
         )

confint <- data.frame(min = min, max = max)
```

Instead of stepping into indexing hell via for loops, you can take advantage of the dataframe structure. A `dataframe` [is a list of vectors](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html#data-frames) and so it is easy to work with `lapply` and `sapply` to iterate through.

If I use `lapply` on a dataframe object itself, it will iterate through each column. You can see this in action by running the simple example below:

```
lapply(data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6, c = 7:9), print)
```

So for your use case you want to iterate through each element of the vector we call by an inital lapply. We can use a nested `sapply` to keep the vector structure.

using our really simple example above, let's say we want to paste "b" into each observation of the dataframe:

```
lapply(data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6, c = 7:9), 
    function(x) {
        sapply(x, 
            function(y) {
                paste(y, "b") }
        )
      }) 
# if we print the above output
$a
[1] "1 b" "2 b" "3 b"

$b
[1] "4 b" "5 b" "6 b"

$c
[1] "7 b" "8 b" "9 b"
```

So we apply the same logic, except instead of pasting "b" we use an `if` `else` statement to either return the original value, or return 0 if the corresponding row (y) in the confint dataframe.

Finally, we want to get a dataframe from our output. So we use do.call to supply the arguments (a list of vectors) to the data.frame() function call.

```
conditional <- 
lapply(reprex[-1], function(x) {
  sapply(seq_along(x), function(y) {
    if(x[y] > confint$min[y] & x[y] < confint$max[y]) {x[y]} else {0}
  })
})

do.call(data.frame, conditional)
```

But for real, if you do this kind of thing often, I recommend taking some time to learn the tidyverse. Tons of time saving tools for tasks like this. Using the tidyverse you could tackle this problem like so:

```
library(tidyverse)
reprex %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Summer")) %>%
  group_by(Coastal_Cities) %>%
  mutate(sd = sd(value),
         mean = mean(value),
         ci_min = mean - 1.96 * sd/n(),
         ci_max = mean + 1.96 * sd/n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(value = case_when(
    ci_min <= value & value <= ci_max ~ value,
    TRUE ~ 0
  ))
```

Comment: This logic is dope! Interested to see the explanation behind this